# Scrapy upload pdf files to specific form(id) using FormRequest.from_response

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to upload pdf files to a website(Flask server) where the forms ids are the filenames

Example of a form with id = 1, so i need to upload the 'arquivos/1.pdf' to it, I'm trying to use the scrapy.FormRequest.from_response but when i try adding the **multipart/form-data** as Content-Type header the server doesn't find or receive the file.

```
<title>Upload 1 new File</title>
    <h1>Upload 1 new File</h1>
    <form id=1 action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
        <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
```

Scrapy code

```
filename = '../arquivos/%s.pdf' % 1    

with open(filename, mode='rb') as file:
                yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formid=1, formdata={'file': file, }, headers={'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})
```

Flask Server Snippet

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.headers)

        print(request.files['file'])
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

When i execute the Scrapy spider my server log gives
[image: server logs]

Answer (score 1):

That functionality is [still in PR](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1954), and I couldn't find any reference to multi part form data in the existing Scrapy docs, which matches your experience.

Feel free to vote for that issue, but otherwise you'll have to generate the request by hand, assuming Scrapy will allow posting a "raw" request body :-(

Comment: I've decided to use selenium instead it's a bit slower but got the job done, thanks for the reply.